# questions regarding string functions like strcat(), strncpy(),strncat()?

Tags: c, string, output, strcat, strncpy

#### code 1

```
int main()
{
    char str[]="abc";
    char str1[]="hello computer";
    strcat(str,str1);
    printf("the concatenated string is : %s\n",str);
    return 0;
}
```

#### output- `abchello computer`

#### code 2

```
int main()
{
    char str[100];  //notice the change from code 1
    char str1[]="hello computer";
    strcat(str,str1);
    printf("the concatenated string is : %s\n",str);
    return 0;
}
```

#### output- `@#^hello computer`

#### code 3

```
int main()
{
    char str[100];
    char str1[]="hello computer";
    strncpy(str,str1,5);
    str[5]='\0';   //external addition of NULL
    printf("the copied string is : %s\n",str);
    return 0;
}
```

#### output- `hello`

#### code 4

```
int main()
{
    char str[100]="abc";
    char str1[]="hello computer";
    strncat(str,str1,5);
    printf("the concatenated string is : %s\n",str);
    return 0;
}
```

#### output- `abchello`

#### QUESTIONS

Q-1) Why `abchello computer` is displayed in `code 1` and `@#^hello computer` in `code 2`? From where the garbage `@#^` is coming?

Q-2) Why external addition of `NULL '\0'` is required in `strncpy()` but not in `strncat()` as shown in `code 3` and `code 4` respectively?

#### NOTE- If in `code 4` I do `char str[100];` then `@#^hello` is displayed,but still the string is ended without addition of NULL

Comment: `'\0'` is `NUL` and different from `NULL`.

Comment: Also the C Standard does **not** require the compiler to generate code that does initialise `auto` variables, not to `0` nor to anything else.

Answer (score 3):

The first example writes beyond the end of str and so has undefined behaviour.

The second example uses strcat which demands two null-terminated strings as arguments. One of your arguments does not meet that requirement because you failed to initialise it.

The third example does not copy a null terminator because that is how strncpy is designed. As you can discern from the documentation, strncpy does not write a null terminator if the destination buffer is smaller than the source string.

As for the fourth example, strncat differs from strncpy in that it always copies a null-terminator.

I do recommend that you refer closely to the documentation of these functions.

Comment: Your first example is hopelessly broken. str is an array of length 4. You overrun the buffer.

Comment: if `strncat` does not write `null` terminator then why string ends correctly

Comment: The variable is not initialised. It could have any value, even null.

Answer (score 3):

#### Code 1

```
char str[]="abc";
char str1[]="hello computer";
strcat(str,str1);
```

This overflows `str`. The behavior is undefined and any output can be assumed (in reality, probably `str1` is being overwritten by itself, that's why you see `abshello computer` as output).

#### Code 2

```
char str[100];  //notice the change from code 1
char str1[]="hello computer";
strcat(str,str1);
```

You see garbage before `hello computer` because `str` is uninitialized. It so happens that it had contained `"@#^"` at the time of your test before its first NUL.

#### Code 3

```
char str[100];
char str1[]="hello computer";
strncpy(str,str1,5);
str[5]='\0';   //external addition of NULL
```

This is correct. `strncpy` copies the first five characters from `"hello computer"` and doesn't NUL-terminate it. You should do that yourself (as you have done). For further reference, from man page of [`strcpy`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy):

> The **strcpy()** function copies the string pointed to by src, including the terminating null byte ('\0'), to the buffer pointed to by dest. The strings may not overlap, and the destination string dest must be large enough to receive the copy. Beware of buffer overruns! (See BUGS.)
>
> The **strncpy()** function is similar, except that at most n bytes of src are copied. **Warning:** If there is no null byte among the first n bytes of src, the string placed in dest will not be null-terminated.

#### Code 4

```
char str[100]="abc";
char str1[]="hello computer";
strncat(str,str1,5);
```

One difference between `strncpy` and `strncat` is that `strncat` NUL-terminates the resulting string. From man page of [`strncat`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncat):

> As with strcat(), the resulting string in dest is always null-terminated.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, it does. `strncpy` copies 5 characters (`hello`) from `"hello computer"` and since NUL is not already met, it gives up and quits. The resulting string is not NUL-terminated.

Comment: but i externally does it

Comment: @Shahbaz I am referring to the destination string. You comment that it is not initialised. But that is fine for strncpy.

Comment: Sorry everyone, in my haste I didn't notice I wrote the wrong thing.

Comment: The contents of the destination before calling strncpy are irrelevant because strncpy overwrites the destination buffer.

Comment: @Shahbaz : by recent edit to your answer you mean to say that both `strcat()` and `strncat()` nul terminates the resultant string

Comment: @learner, that is true. If you read the links to the man pages, all the details are there.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, my mistake (I had added the fourth line of code after I wrote the paragraph). The contents are still important (the contents at index `5` in particular) which is in this case later overwritten to be `NUL`. If it wasn't overwritten to `NUL`, then its previous value should have been `NUL` for it to work. Anyway, useless conversation now, we both know what's the correct thing.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, thanks for telling me! You see, that's why I don't do anything under C++ tag anymore. If this was under C++ tag, I'd have gotten 5 downvotes and 10 angry comments calling me stupid or something.

Answer (score 0):

As David said, for strcat it expects null terminated string so thatmay be he possible reason for the garbage value.

For your code 3, the '\0' character at the last of the string represents a char array as string, with out '\0' terminating it is just a char array not a valid string. Since you are printing by using %s , compiler requires to be it as string.

Answer (score 0):

> Q-1) Why abchello computer is displayed in code 1 and @#^hello
>   computer in code 2? From where the garbage @#^ is coming?

**In Code2: "char str[100] contains uninitialized garbage characters".**

Try running the Code2 program multiple times. You may see that the garbage characters at the beginning of the string change every time you run it. `char str[100]` reserves a place in memory where you can store 100 characters in a row, but it does not clean it out for you. Anything left in memory from a previous program is often referred to as 'garbage'. That memory almost certainly contains random data from the last time the memory was used. Sometimes you can even find readable strings in uninitialized memory like this.

When you run strcat, the program needs to figure out where the end of the string in 'str' is. The problem is, there was never a proper string put into str - it is just full of garbage. The program starts at the beginning of the char str[100] buffer and looks for a '\0' character that indicates the end of the string. It will find one eventually (a random '\0\ will eventually shown up somewhere in memory) and declare that to the be the end of the first string. It now considers everything before the first '\0' to be part of the official string.

Try this: add the following line right before the `strcat: str[0]='\0';` The program should now run without showing the garbage characters.